# how to measure or understand websocket / socket application?

Tags: sockets, websocket

In my understanding, websocket/socket has the ability to:

1. broadcasting: publish messages to the public channel
2. private chat room: send messages to a private channel.

so my question is:

1. when broadcasting to a public channel, will the CPU grow high when receiver increase from 10 to 1000 ?
2. when send message to a private channel, is there any tools to measure / optimize?

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

A Websocket and also a normal TCP socket are a one-to-one connection between a single client and a single server. There is no way to broadcast anything and there is no concept of public or private channels. There might be applications/protocols which implement such concepts on top of Websockets or plain sockets but the behavior would be specific for this application/protocol then.